# xquery vs. xpath performance

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, database-performance, sqlxml

Is there any difference between xquery and xpath performance in SQL Server 2008?

I'm very new to XML sql data type, and I would like to store document details as XML in SQL Server 2008 while performance of queries on this field is very important.

Do you have any experience of performance differences between xquery and xpath?

Comment: There is no clear distinction between these two things (at least not in SQL Server).  So you should post simple examples of what you wish for us to compare.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I simply want to Query over 14,000,000 documents stored as XML field in SQL Server! I generate 1,000,000 rows in data base to test now, but simple select with no where condition takes about 3 minutes. I also applied XML Indexing but it's still not acceptable in performance. Similar scenario takes 19 Sec for similar table which have all fields as typed.

Comment: Again: we'll need more specific examples in order to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my experience, OpenXML function is the best solution for xml parsing in SQL server, especially for huge data volume.
Please refer this link.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186918.aspx